# Creating and printing svg for business cards

Tags: inkscape, digital-printing

I've created this [svg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18s8A56WnoYYVr1_-AlTtWXzmiL8aWB4-/view?usp=sharing) with guidelines defining the size of business cards for Avery 5871. When I print it out, it is slightly too small, 1/8" on top, right, left, and 1/4" on bottom.

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

[image: page setup dialog]

Comment: Please take the time to add the actual instructions you followed, rather than just posting a youtube link. It will a) prevent link-rot should the video ever be taken down & b) save someone having to watch 7 minutes of video to try figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. The link to the video was just an aside, really all one needs to do is look at the file. I will edit the question.

Comment: It sounds like you have "fit to page" turned on, or whatever the similar setting is in Inkscape.

Comment: The file seems to have right object dimensions. Inkscape has in "document properties" a possibility to scale the graphics, but it seems to be unused. I tested printing it (removed other rectangles than the 4 corner items) The printed page size was right within half a millimeter. Your printer driver settings or the printer itself distorts the dimensions. I used thin office paper. Try with it, too. The printer can feed thick papers differently.

Comment: SVG isn't designed for printing. Many print drivers may not understand the underlying XML.

Comment: That looks like the software settings, what are the printer settings?

Comment: This sounds very much like a print setting problem to me (because I have experienced this problem before).  Make sure you have set the scaling in your print dialog to 100% or "none".  The actual setting will depend on your print driver. They're all a bit different. Also, rather than print directly from Inkscape, it might be better to export to PDF, and open it in Adobe Reader, and print it from there. I've had problems printing directly from Inkscape before. It can be a bit flaky.

Comment: So, 2 things get me there:  1. Print pdf, not svg 1. Print pdf from windows, not linux. Must  be something off with this particular print linux driver. And my mistake for not mention I was working from linux.